# Visual Studio, Debug project that calls another project within the same solution file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution in Visual studio with two projects. One project is a launcher application (calls different executable depending on the arguments, similar to how VS launches the approriate version depending on the .sln file) and the second project contains the executable called by the launcher.

Is there a way to debug the launcher AND the call to second program?

I found some posts about setting up multiple startup projects, however, these do not suit my needs because I am not starting the launcher and the application simultaneously, but in sequence.

I can open the project in vs 2012 or 2013 so I am open to solutions for either version. Thanks

Comment: Assuming both projects are in the same solution, there shouldn't be any issue with debugging the second program if you start up the first. When you launch the startup project in your solution, it should load debugging symbols for both projects.

Comment: @NickBailey maybe its the way I have my launcher set up. Currently the launcher creates a process to call the appropriate exe. When I call the exe VS isn't connected to the new process. Does this sound like the right way to implement my launcher so that VS should load debug info for the newly launched process? I hope that made sense, thanks

Comment: Why don't you debug the target application itself? You could pass command line arguments when starting the debugger.

Comment: @Stefan That is currently what I'm doing, and I'm fine sticking with that if no other method exists. I was just curious if I could debug both portions. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I was a little confused there, you are actually calling the .exe as an executable, rather than invoking methods from it as a linked library. Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: @NickBailey Honestly, I didn't know I could directly call the methods. After I included the appropriate namespaces it all worked well. Thanks for this tip! I am extremely grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to debug the launcher AND the call to second program?

Unless it's different application (external application) you shouldn't face any issue debugging the same.

In case, pressing `F11` doesn't jumps to a method in second project; you can explicitly put a break point in that method in second project and then `F11` should be able to hit the same.

If it's a external application; then you will have to `attach to debugger` by selecting `Debug Menu -> Attach To Process` and then debugger will be able to hit the break point.